# Is there a command like head but for line truncation?

Tags: text-processing, software-rec

Linux's `head` selects a number of lines from the top of a file.  Is there a command that selects a number of characters from the front of a line?

The use case behind the question is this: I want to `head` the first 10 lines from a file, but each of those 10 lines is extremely long and contain lots of white space, making it hard to discern where the line breaks are.

It would be much easier to get a general idea of the contents of the file if I could `head` the first 10 lines, but only view the first 50 characters of each line.

Comment: See also `tput rmam` to disable the terminal's wrapping or piping the output to `less -S`, or `:set nowrap` in `vi`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html):

```
head -n 10 bigfile | cut -c 1-50
```

Comment: redirection isn't needed here...`cut -c 1-50 bigfile | head -n 10` is IMO more readable.

Comment: I've been searching Google for about 3 hours for an answer to this question, it's to simple to create an actual question for it though. I would like to know which way is preferred between "-c 1-50" vs. "-c1-50" (based on the extra space between the argument and the value I suppose) would you happen to know which way is preferred?

Comment: @Jacob Based on the [POSIX argument and syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) and the [POSIX spec for `cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html), I'd always include a space (it helps readability as well), although it seems that omitting the blank *should* still work.

Comment: @jw013 thanks for your answer and the links, that's exactly what I was looking for.