# Extracting specific range of characters from each line

Tags: shell-script, shell

I need to select 10 characters from each line.I have a file like this

```
TestSampleSampleSampleSample
Test1Test2Testtest4Test10Test11
lksdnlkdod
```

I need to modify it so it looks like:

```
 TestSample
 Tes1Test2T
 lksdnlkdod
```

Comment: 10 characters, you mean? And where did you get so far?

Comment: i mean characters .instead of printing whole line i need to print 10 characters of each line

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49792/60069

Comment: Hey Naresh, IDK if it's possible since your question has been flagged, but would you consider to accept an answer? [Mathieu's one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307309/364080) could help in my research!

Answer (score 3):

You can use cut to process the whole file line by line:

```
cut -c -10 < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple way of doing that.

- With `sed`:

```sh
# Posix Regex
sed -e 's/\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/'

# Extended Regex
sed -Ee 's/(.{10}).*/\1/'
```

- With `awk`:

```sh
awk '{ print substr($0, 1, 10) }'
```

- With perl:

```sh
# first way - classic one line
perl -ane 'print $1."\n" if /(.{10})/'

# second way - with field separator
perl -F"(.{10})" -ane 'print $F[1]."\n"'
```

or with `cut` (see *@gnp* answer).